# Does JavaScript realpathSync() also check existence of the file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

I am intending to use node.js FileSystem realpathSync()
to determine the real path of a file. Does realpathSync()
also check whether the file exists. Is it enough to do:

```
        try {
            res = fs.realpathSync(path);
        } catch (err) {
            /* file does not exist or some other I/O error */
        }
```

Or should I also to:

```
        if (!fs.existsSync(res)) {
            /* file does not exist */
        }
```

If yes, is existsSync() free of I/O errors, or does it possibly also
throw some error? In either case, concerning the thrown error err,
how can I divide apart existence error from other I/O errors?

Comment: What if you delete the file, and use `realpathSync()` on it? What happens? Does it complain the file doesn't exist? That's what I'd do, a simple experiment.

Comment: Yes `realpathSync()` will check if file exists with `lstat`. You could compare `err.code` to `ENOENT` to discrimine 'no such file error' to other I/O errors.

Answer (score 1):

realpathSync() does indeed throw an error in case the file or directory doesn't exist. But a nifty detail, err.code is a string and not some number. So I went with the following solution:

```
    try {
        res = fs.realpathSync(path);
    } catch (err) {
        if (err.code === "ENOENT") {
           /* file or directory does not exist */
        } else {
           /* some other I/O error */
        }
    }
```